# Why is my PHP urlencode not functioning as examples on internet?

Tags: php, web, encode

Why does my `urlencode()` produce something different than I expected?

This might be my expectations being wrong but then I would be even more puzzled.

example

```
urlencode("ä");

expectations = returns %C3%A4

reality = returns %E4
```

Where have I gone wrong in my expections? It seems to be linked to encoding. But I'm not very familiar in what I should do/use.

Should I change something on my server to that the function uses the right encoding?

Comment: Not sure: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a9f0a4606f0fac02c0874b75a849fc5143f4f6e

Comment: Thank for that site. But it seems to confirm my expectations and push me deeper into confusion about my own php behaviour. Why would mine give back the wrong data?

Comment: Maybe your file is not UTF-8 encoded? Not really sure.

Comment: According to the PHP manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), the output of urlencode is "a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits". Looks like that's exactly what you are getting. And the value matches various encoding tables available online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urlencode` encodes the raw bytes in your string into a percent-encoded representation. If you expect `%C3%A4` that means you expect the UTF-8 byte representation of "ä". If you get `%E4` that means your string is *actually* encoded in ISO-8859-1 instead.

Encode your string in UTF-8 to get the expected result. How to do this depends on where this string comes from. If it's a string literal in your source code file, save the file as UTF-8 in your text editor. If it comes from a database, see [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/476).

For more background information, see [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: Thank you very much, my file format was defaulted to ANSI. When i put it in utf-8 it solved my problems.